# How many "imports" does python allow in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm starting in Python and I would like to know how many import's python allows within a file?

Comment: It really depends on how much your computer can handle and not a general limit in python if im not mistaken.

Comment: More than you need, unless you are doing something ludicrous.

Answer (score 0):

The number of imports in a module is not limited in Python. If any implementation has a restriction, it's most likely due to resource constraints outside of the Python interpreter. (PC SPECS: CPU, RAM, etc)